# New command for automatic enumerate generation

Tags: macros, enumerate, automation

I was thinking about a macro with only one argument, but of varibale length expanding the parameters into an enumeration.

---

E.g.:

```
  \dostuff{a}
```

expand to

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item a.
\end{enumerate}
```

and

```
  \dostuff{a, b, c}
```

expand to

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item a,
  \item b,
  \item c.
\end{enumerate}
```

---

Since tex commands can only handle up to 9 arguments, a solution based on a set of arguments would not be a good solution for (and would be an ugly solution as well) i think.

Is there some (hacky?) way to do this?

Comment: There a ways of using more than 9 arguments but in this sense it's not recommended!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `expl3` (the upcoming LaTeX 3 ;-)) this is pretty easy, by using a `\seq` variable, storing the comma separate list and expanding it with `\seq_map_inline:Nn`

Since `expl3` is pretty stable meanwhile and no really new feature of `expl3` is used the following code should work even with an older version of `expl3` (I loaded `xparse` to use `\NewDocumentCommand`, but a `\newcommand` would do as well)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn%

\seq_new:N \l_local_enum_seq

\newcommand{\storethestuff}[1]{%
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_local_enum_seq {#1}%
}

\newcommand{\dotheenumstuff}{%
\int_zero:N \l_tmpa_int
\seq_map_inline:Nn \l_local_enum_seq {%
    \int_incr:N \l_tmpa_int% Increase the counter
    \item ##1
    % Check whether the list has reached the end -- if so, use '.' instead of ','
    \int_compare:nNnTF 
     { \l_tmpa_int } < {\seq_count:N \l_local_enum_seq} 
     {,} {.}
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\NewDocumentCommand{\dostuff}{+m}{%
  \storethestuff{#1}%
  \begin{enumerate}
    \dotheenumstuff%
  \end{enumerate}
}

\begin{document}
\dostuff{a,b,c,d,e,f,some more stuff}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**The old version with just one command**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn%

\seq_new:N \l_local_enum_seq


\NewDocumentCommand{\dostuff}{o+m}{%
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_local_enum_seq {#2}%
   \int_zero:N \l_tmpa_int
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
   \begin{enumerate}[#1]
   }{%      
     \begin{enumerate}
    }
   \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_local_enum_seq {%
    \int_incr:N \l_tmpa_int
    \item ##1
    \int_compare:nNnTF { \l_tmpa_int } < {\seq_count:N \l_local_enum_seq} {%
  , } {.}
   }
  \end{enumerate}
 }

 \ExplSyntaxOff


 \begin{document}
 \dostuff[label={Something with spaces}]{a,b,c,d,e,f,some more stuff}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks pretty solution as far as I understand! This is nearly what i want :) could you expand it to my desired commas and the end dot :)

Comment: @user69453: See the update please.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Is there a reason of using the two intermediate commands instead of defining it directly in `\dostuff`?

Comment: @Tobi: Take a look at the first version of my post -- some will frown on the first version, others criticise this version ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Hm … I can’t se a difference … all revisions define `\storethestuff` and `\dotheenumstuff`. I’d define only `\dostuff` to do all the work or at least protect the “internal” macros from users. However if it’s just a question of preference I’m fine. I just wondered if there is a _real_ argument for either version …

Comment: @Tobi: Oh my, apparently, the original version vanished because I edited in the 5 minutes grace period. Actually, it was what you suggested: Just one command

Comment: @Tobi: Added the old version (with some improvements) -- The second version separates `expl3` content and document level content more clearly, in my point of view.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Thanks :-) I prefer the singe maraca version B-)

Comment: where did you specify the seperator?

Comment: @user69453: Which separator?

Comment: The seperator which seperates the values in ``\dostuff``

Comment: @user69453: The line with `{,} {.}`

Comment: this is about how it is displayed, but not how the macro treads the``\dostuff{a,b,c}`` - how do I make this macro work with ``\dostuff{a;b;c}``

Comment: well, your changing the question right now

Answer (score 2):

`expl3` has several features; in this case, `\seq_use:Nn` seems to be the best choice.

We start `enumerate`, split the argument at commas (or the character specified in the optional argument, issue `\item` and then hand each element of the sequence, with `,\item` between them. A trailing period ends the job.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_egreg_enum_seq

\NewDocumentCommand{\dostuff}{O{,}m}
 {
  \begin{enumerate}
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_egreg_enum_seq {#1} {#2}
  \item
  \seq_use:Nn \l_egreg_enum_seq { , \item }
  .
  \end{enumerate}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\dostuff{a,b,c,d,e,f,some more stuff}

\dostuff[;]{a; b; c; some, stuff}

\end{document}
```

[image]