# Vertical spacing after enumeration in table altough all seps are set to zero

Tags: tables, itemize, enumitem

I have a strange vertical spacing after a `\enumeration` in a table although I have set all seps to `0pt` (`[itemsep=0pt, topsep=0pt, parsep=0pt, partopsep=0pt]`.
I want zero vertical spacing after the enumeration.

MWE

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xparse}

%compressed lists
% usage: Now just use \compress before \begin{itemize}.
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother

 %% cmd for table generation
\newcommand{\cTable}[5] % caption - a- b - c - label
{
  \begin{table}[ht!]
    \caption{{#1}}
    \begin{tabular}{p{3.4cm} p{11cm}}
      \textbf{\raggedright -a}          & {#2}   \\
      \textbf{\raggedright -b}          & {#3}   \\
      \textbf{\raggedright -c}          & {#4}
    \end{tabular}
  \label{#5}
  \end{table}
}
%% end cmd for table generation

%% cmd for item generation
%% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317680/new-command-for-automatic-enumerate-generation
\ExplSyntaxOn%

\seq_new:N \l_local_enum_seq

\newcommand{\storethestuff}[1]{%
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_local_enum_seq {#1}%
}

\newcommand{\dotheenumstuff}{%
\int_zero:N \l_tmpa_int
\seq_map_inline:Nn \l_local_enum_seq {%
    \int_incr:N \l_tmpa_int% Increase the counter
    \item ##1
    % Check whether the list has reached the end -- if so, use '.' instead of ','
    \int_compare:nNnTF 
     { \l_tmpa_int } < {\seq_count:N \l_local_enum_seq} 
     {,} {.}
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\dostuff}{+m}{%
  \storethestuff{#1}%
  \compress
  \begin{enumerate}[itemsep=0pt, topsep=0pt, parsep=0pt, partopsep=0pt, leftmargin=*]
    \dotheenumstuff%
  \end{enumerate}
}
%% end cmd for item generation

\begin{document}

\cTable
    {this is a caption}
    {value of a}
    {\dostuff{1,1,1,1,11}}
    {value of c} %value of c needs to be a list
    {tab:exampleTab}

\end{document}
```

Strange vertical spacing
[image: Image for strange vertical spacing in table after enumeration]

---

**EDIT**

The solution provivide in [A list inside a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54039/a-list-inside-a-table) looked way to complex to be a solution to this simple problem. Furthermore the solution in comments to use `\baselineskip` works perfectly and is not given as an answer in the referenced question. Therefore I would want to leave this as an extra question, since, with the answer in the comment, there is a very good solution to the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A list inside a table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54039/a-list-inside-a-table)

Comment: Consider adding `after={\vspace{-\baselineskip}}` to your list of `enumerate` options.

Comment: make this a answer and I accpect it - works perfectly :)

Comment: @user69453: Sorry for the delay. Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add

```
after={\vspace{-\baselineskip}}
```

to the list of `enumerate` options you currently have. This should revert the empty line following the list.